# add slice of data from a dataframe to a time series dataframe based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes. df1 is a time series with 6 columns of values, one of which is column 'name'. df2 is a list of rows each with a unique string in the 'name' column and a the same date in each row of the 'date' column---all rows have the same date value from an observation that occurred on same date.

df1-->

| Date | name | score | stat1 | stat2 | pick |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1-1 | ABC | 23.3 | 0.234 | 34 | NaN |
| 2022-1-2 | ABC | 21.1 | 0.431 | 14 | NaN |
| 2022-1-3 | ABC | 29.9 | 1.310 | 4 | NaN |
| 2022-1-4 | ABC | 11.3 | 9.310 | 3 | NaN |

df1 Index is Date

df2-->

| index | Date | name | pick |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-1-3 | QRS | 23.3 |
| 1 | 2022-1-3 | ABC | 21.1 |
| 2 | 2022-1-3 | DBA | 29.9 |
| 3 | 2022-1-3 | KLL | 11.3 |

I would like to merge / add the row from df2 to the row in df1 where 'name' and 'date' criteria are met.

I've reviewed many articles here and elsewhere as well as trying .merge as follows:

```
    df3['pick'] = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['name'])
```

Success is to get df2 or a new df3 to look like this:

| Date | name | score | stat1 | stat2 | pick |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1-1 | ABC | 23.3 | 0.234 | 34 | NaN |
| 2022-1-2 | ABC | 21.1 | 0.431 | 14 | NaN |
| 2022-1-3 | ABC | 29.9 | 1.310 | 4 | 21.1 |
| 2022-1-4 | ABC | 11.3 | 9.310 | 3 | NaN |

Where df1 is updated based on the relevant row from df2 OR a new df3 is the resulting combination of df1 and df2 where the 'pick' value of 21.1 is inserted to match the appropriate date and name.

Guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Date', 'name']) # what this line does is it merges df1 and df2 based on the 'Date' and 'name' columns. The resulting df1 has the 'pick' column from df2 appended to it.
df1['pick'] = df1['pick_y'].fillna(df1['pick_x']) # this line replaces the NaN values in the 'pick' column with the values from the 'pick_x' column.
df1 = df1.drop(['pick_x', 'pick_y', 'index'], axis=1) # this line drops the 'pick_x', 'pick_y' and 'index' columns as they are no longer needed.
```

**output:**

```
       Date name score  stat1 stat2  pick
0  2022-1-1  ABC  23.3  0.234    34   NaN
1  2022-1-2  ABC  21.1  0.431    14   NaN
2  2022-1-3  ABC  29.9   1.31     4  21.1
3  2022-1-4  ABC  11.3   9.31     3   NaN
```

Comment: Thx! Glad to see it works well when you try it My version is resulting in a keyerror on the second line of your suggested code. Will keep trying it here. Any addtl thoughts most welcome.

Comment: If you would provide more rest cases, we might write something to cover everything.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! I had an issue with column names in source files that were the reason for KeyError. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', left_on=['Date','name'], right_on=['Date','name'])
```

Comment: Thx! Now getting a keyerror as: <class 'KeyError'> when I try this approach. The specific key is not called out but the line reference is this line of code suggested.

Comment: With my corrections to column names, this approach works also! Thank you.

Comment: Nice to know that!